# How to ignore specific directory to not include during Get sources in TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, tfvc

I have an Automation Build definition in TFS which points to the main build (Central repo).

When I run the Automation build in TFS, though the Clean is set to false, during Get Source the build redownloads all the files again from the central repo and fails due to server times out because of the size.

[image]

I want to ignore a directory from Central repo to Automation Build during Get Sources process, is there any way to do it?  or I don't know if there is a way to stop redownloading again when the Clean is set to false.

I don't want to delete the directory from the Centrol repo because it is a dependency, while in Automation build I am handling that dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a second line to the mapping and set it to `cloak` that will cause it to be ignored when getting the sources.

You may want to also make sure that folder is not part of your CI trigger folders in that case.

Comment: Do you know of any reason why the get source process redownloading unchanged files even when Clean is set to false?

Comment: Can you run a build with diagnostics turned on and share the log for the get sources step? If needed privately?